# how to get top n rows from a table where value of n is passed at run-time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to get top n rows from a table where value of n is passed at run-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and beyond you can actually parameterise the top command.

The code below is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
DECLARE @p AS int;
SELECT @p=10
SELECT TOP(@p)*
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server you will need to either use rowcount or dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set rowcount`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) To get the first 100, for example:

```
declare @myrowcount = 100

set rowcount @myrowcount      
select ..... from ... where...order by
```

since you can use either of:

> SET ROWCOUNT { number | @number_var }

Comment: This can give odd results. David Hall's answer will give correct results

Comment: @gbn: what kind of odd results?

Comment: As per BOL: SET ROWCOUNT: "Causes SQL Server to stop processing the query after the specified number of rows are returned." TOP: "Specifies that only the first set of rows will be returned from the query result". Example: http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/04/20/set-rowcount-and-table-functions/