# SQL stored procedure problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LockRoots
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @lock uniqueidentifier,
    @count int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE R
    SET R.[Lock] = @lock
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP @count *
        FROM [Root] as R
        --LEFT JOIN [Container] as C ON R.ID = C.RootID
        WHERE [Lock] IS NULL
        --ORDER BY NEWID()
    );
END
GO
```

The problem occurs with "SELECT TOP **@count** *", why can't I "select top @VariableAmount" of records?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get top n rows from a table where value of n is passed at run-time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260767/how-to-get-top-n-rows-from-a-table-where-value-of-n-is-passed-at-run-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Need parenthesis...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
...
SELECT TOP (@count) *
...
```

Note: also SQL Server 2005+ for parameterised TOP